# Can I force Kubernetes not to run more than X replicas of a pod in the same node?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

I have a tiny Kubernetes cluster consisting of just two nodes running on `t3a.micro` AWS EC2 instances (to save money).

I have a small web app that I am trying to run in this cluster. I have a single [`Deployment`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) for this app. This deployment has `spec.replicas` set to 4.

When I run this `Deployment`, I noticed that Kubernetes scheduled 3 of its pods in one node and 1 pod in the other node.

Is it possible to force Kubernetes to schedule at most 2 pods of this `Deployment` per node? Having 3 instances in the same pod puts me dangerously close to running out of memory in these tiny EC2 instances.

Thanks!

Comment: set up resource requests to not run out of memory, but dont mess with the decisions of the scheduler, unless you have a reason. this is not a reason.

Comment: @suren thanks for the suggestion. I will add a memory limit, but I would still prefer Kubernetes to schedule the pods evenly among nodes. Another reason for that is that if the 3-pod node hard-dies before having time to drain gracefully, I will lose 75% of my capacity for a while (until replacement pods are rescheduled). Likewise, if Kubernetes decides to schedule all 4 pods in the same node and that node hard-dies then I have an outage for a while.

Having all replicas evenly distributed among nodes seems safer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct solution for this would be to set memory requests and limits correctly matching your steady state and burst RAM consumption levels on every pod, then the scheduler will do all this math for you.

But for the future and for others, there is a new feature which kind of allows this https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/05/introducing-podtopologyspread/. It's not an exact match, you can't put a global cap, rather you can require pods be evenly spaced over the cluster subject to maximum skew caps.

Comment: Thanks! `PodTopologySpread` looks exactly like what I was looking for. Hitting memory limits is not the only reason why I was interested in this; Another reason is that if the 3-pod node hard-dies before having time to drain gracefully, I will lose 75% of my capacity for a while (until replacement pods are rescheduled). Similarly, If Kubernetes decides to schedule all 4 pods in the same node and that node hard-dies then I have an outage for a while. Having all replicas evenly distributed among nodes seems safer.